# can't update an event having attachments in outlook using rest api

Tags: python-requests, outlook-restapi

I am trying to update the event using patch request.
When I am updating the data, it works fine.
code looks like this->

```
url = "https://outlook.office365.com/api/v2.0/users('{email_id}')/events/{event_id}"
data = {
        "BodyPreview": "Updaed Hello Mr. with attachment"
        }
req = url.format(email_id=email_id, event_id=event_id)
resp = requests.patch(url=req, json=data, headers=HEADERS)
```

But when I am trying to create attachments in this event, it is giving me an error.

```
url = "https://outlook.office365.com/api/v2.0/users('{email_id}')/events/{event_id}/attachments"   
req = url.format(email_id=email_id, event_id=event_id)
data = {
        "Name": "t1",
        "@odata.type": "#Microsoft.OutlookServices.FileAttachment",
        "ContentBytes": "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"
    }
resp = requests.patch(url=req, json=data, headers=HEADERS)
#print(HEADERS)
print(resp)
resp = resp.json()
print(resp)
```

This is the error message I am getting for this.

```
The OData request is not supported.', u'code': u'ErrorInvalidRequest'}}
```

Answer (score 0):

You using the wrong type of request you should be doing a POST to create an Attachment on an item https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/office/office-365-api/api/version-2.0/mail-rest-operations#CreateAttachments

You can't update attachments you can only create or delete them think of them as a separate item associated with the underlying object.

Comment: It works fine with POST but what if I want to ignore the request if the attachment is already present in the calendar event. Because POST creates a new event every time. I only want to create it when it is not present. What request and logic should I use?

Comment: As i already mentioned you can only create and Delete attachments with the REST API (its the same for EWS as well). So in the case you mentioned you will need to do a Get to work out if the attachments exists which should be very easy.